# Xtext editor to insert single proposals automatically without showing content assist popup

Tags: autocomplete, xtext, content-assist

In my Xtext editor I want to enable **insert single proposals automatically** by default.
In essence what want is to have auto completion when there is only one matching choice to show up in content assist when we hit Ctrl-Space.

In eclipse(java editor) this can be configured from *Windows->Preferences* go to *Java->Editor->Content Assist* page and select "insert single proposals automatically" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [set auto-insertable](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.1.0/org/eclipse/xtext/ui/editor/contentassist/ConfigurableCompletionProposal.html#setAutoInsertable%28boolean%29) to `true` for you completion proposal. If it is the only proposal added to the acceptor, it should be inserted automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this, but it does not work for me. Here is the link with details: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/269009/769500/#msg_769500